# Python - looping over files - order

Tags: python

Does anyone know how Python arranges files when looping over them?
I need to loop over some files in a folder in a fixed order (preferably alphanumerically according to the filenames), but Python seems to loop over them in a rather random order.
So far I am using this code:

```
filelist = glob.glob(os.path.join(path, 'FV/*.txt'))
for infile in filelist: 
  #do some fancy stuff
  print str(infile)
```

and the filenames are printed in an order not really obvious to me.

Is there any simple way to predefine a certain order for that loop?
Thanks!

Comment: just for the sake of completeness: If you just want to iterate through files os.listdir often suffices (... not in your case, because you want to expand *.txt).

Answer (score 39, accepted):

As far as I can see in the docs, [`glob.glob()`](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/glob.html) has no defined order. Given this, the easiest way to be sure is to sort the list returned to you:

```
filelist = glob.glob(os.path.join(path, 'FV/*.txt'))
for infile in sorted(filelist): 
  #do some fancy stuff
  print str(infile)
```

This will just sort as strings - which gives the simple fixed order you were looking for. If you need a specific order, then [`sorted()`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sorted) takes `key` as a keyword argument, which is a function that gives sort order. See the documentation (linked previously) for more.

Comment: Beat me to it.  Alphanumeric is the default sorting for strings, correct? +1

Comment: @BlackVegetable Yeah, it'll just be a simple sort - obviously, you could define a `key` function to sort however you wanted.

Comment: Perhaps you could edit your answer to include that information as well as a note about `reverse`?

Comment: @BlackVegetable I added a short note, it shouldn't be hard to find more on `sorted()` if the OP needs it from here.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to iterate over the file just alphabetically (instead of alphanumerically) you will want to make it case-insensitive by calling sorted in the following way:

```
    filelist = glob.glob(os.path.join(path, 'FV/*.txt'))
    for infile in sorted(filelist, key=lambda s: s.lower()): 
      #do some fancy stuff
      print str(infile)
```

Otherwise, just use the sorted function on filelist.

Answer (score -3):

```
import os
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(os.path.join(path, 'FV/'), topdown=True):
  print root
  print files.sort(reverse=True)
```

It's an alternative..
(considering that `glob.glob()` takes no parameter for ordering items, i just presented an alternative to `glob.glob()` which is, `walk()`.. It takes parameters that could be useful and I think that the downvotes are unfair but hey everyone's entitled to their opinion -.-)

Comment: -1, This isn't equivalent. `walk()` gives all files, and goes into subdirectories.

Comment: break if you don't like to go into subdirectories. `walk()` gives you control, it doesn't do things that you don't explicitly don't want it to do.

Comment: It's rather silly to use `walk` when you don't want to recurse into subdirectories. And there's no guarantee that `walk` gives you files in alphabetical order as you claim.

Comment: Again, `walk()` will give you programatical way of parsing objects based on their type and (again) what you descide to do. `glob.glob()` will just spit in your face a list of everything of the folder you gave it. for instance, `glob.glob('C:\Documents and Settings\myuser\Desktop\*')` will give you a unsorted, undefined list of stuff.. It's at least IMO not best practice to parse a "ls /path/" when there's a way to actually grab items by type.

Comment: Your code isn't even correct because `walk` takes a directory name and not a wildcard.

Comment: @interjay thank you for pointing that out. Copied the OPs path to connect my answer a bit more to the problem described (instead of using `C:\\`. Anyway, `walk()` is again IMO the best practice, at least it takes parameters.

Comment: Regarding your previous comment: `walk` and `glob` are different tools with different uses. If you want all `*.txt` files in a directory as OP does, then `glob` is the correct tool to use while `walk` isn't.

Comment: I don't really get your point at all. `glob.glob()` does what the asker wants, you are trying to hack `walk()` to do the same thing (and not succeeding, as it still doesn't get only text files), but why do that when there is something designed for the job.

Comment: "files when looping over them" == `glob.glob()` doesn't loop over files, it loops over a list of everything including folders. Ergo, i just presented a way to actually loop over files, with sorting functionality. That's it.. i don't hack `walk` in any way, it's a more complex and complete function than `glob.glob` which is actually a "hack" to get what you want if you're in a hurry.